# Como salvar um gráfico em uma imagem PNG?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Eu tenho alguns dados de um experimento, e gostaria de salvá-los como PNG. Para exibir os dados, eu simplesmente faço o `show()`. Porém, gostaria de salvar diretamente como PNG para não tirar print da tela.

Como eu faço para exibir meus dados:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = (
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,4),
    (4,7)
    # mais umas 300 linhas de dados do experimento...
)

x = [d[0] for d in data]
y = [d[1] for d in data]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Como faço para salvar a imagem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O mesmo objeto `pyplot` referenciado por `plt` possui o método [`savefig`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html):

> ```
> savefig(fname, dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
>         orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
>         transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
>         frameon=None, metadata=None)
> ```

Assim, se precisa salvar o gráfico, basta fazer:

```
plt.savefig('resultado.png')
```

Os parâmetros do método são:

- `fname`, uma *string* que indica o caminho onde será salvada a imagem ou o objeto de um arquivo já aberto pelo Python;
- `dpi`, a resolução em pontos por polegada;
- `quality`, qualidade de imagem entre 1 e 100; quanto maior melhor, só utilizado quando o formato é JPG ou JPEG;

Outros parâmetros são bem menos usados e podem ser vistos direto na documentação.

**Exemplo:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x = range(20)
y = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(20)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'o')

plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

Produziu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método [savefig](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig), como no exemplo:

```
pylab.savefig('foo.png')
```

Do próprio `pyplot`

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622163/save-plot-to-image-file-instead-of-displaying-it-using-matplotlib)